# Regular expression to find and replace a string in a xml

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm looking for one regular expression that could match a string for three specific cases in a xml file:

1. : Double-quotes surrounding a string.
2. : A string surrounded by the characters **greater than** and **Less Than**.
3. : A string surrounded by the characters **;** and **&**.

Example:

- **"MyString"** - Valid match

  **>MyString<** - Valid match

  **;MyString&** - Valid match

Other possible combinations are invalid match.

**"MyString<** - Invalid match

**;MyString"** - Invalid match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: `("MyString")|(>MyString<)|(;MyString&)`

Comment: I think he means any string between " ", > < or ; &

Comment: He can replace "MyString" with whatever he wants, even another regular expression.  He used MyString, so I did too.

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot use regex to parse xml, it is not a regular grammar. Use an xml parser, seriously.**

When you're using your parser to inspect text node values *then and only then* you might want to use `(\".*?\")|(>.*?<)|(;.*?&)` but I doubt you'll find the problem is framed the same way. >MyString< is *very* suspicious.

Comment: I understand that this is a common refrain, but nevertheless you should change the "You cannot" part to "You should not"! ;-)

Comment: I see what you're saying but on what technical grounds? You *cannot* do this with any reliability. "should not" implies that actually sometimes it's ok if you throw an unhandled exception.

Comment: In some situations a "quick and dirty" solution outweighs a "clean and polished" one.  Regex is perfectly acceptable for processing text (XML formatted or not) in some situations.

Comment: Especially if the xml might be malformed.  XML parsers hate malformed XML.  Regular expressions don't care.

Comment: I agree with you on this point and when I need to process an xml file I'm using an xml parser. In this case, I'm receiving a bunch of different formatted xml file (I dont know the format) and I need to convert them for another project. The only thing I know is the strings to convert can be in an attribute or in an inner text of an element. Per example, every Plant.Unit1.Current needs to be changed to Plant.Unit2.Current.

Comment: So, I'm not parsing any xml in this case, I'm just doing a simple search and replace.

Comment: Regex may be overkill and slower compared to just using the Replace member function of string.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I will check that.